# Transformer 45517: power supply or charger?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, electronics, battery

I would like to build a charging station for EV3 with rechargeable battery (45501).

Does the transformer (45517) give a simple stable dc voltage (power supply)? Or does it provide a controlled voltage / current depending on the charge with charging a method (CC-CV or other)? What is the charging method?

In other words: the charging intelligence is in the rechargeable battery or in the transformer?

Answer (score 4):

The charging circuit is in the battery, so any 10V, 700mA DC power supply should work. The circuit driven by a [MP26123](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP26123/document_id/1398) chip.

The battery schematic is available from the *EV3 Hardware Developer Kit* on the [MINDSTORMS download page](https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/downloads) for anyone who wants to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks a lot David for your very completed answer.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer if you find this helpful (it helps other people find the answer too).